# Custom region not showing up in drupal 7

Tags: drupal

I created custom region and put there block but when I logged out this region with block inside not showing up.

Comment: Maybe your block is set to be shown only to logged in users? :)

Comment: No in settings this block is visible for all roles

Comment: Did you clear the cache?

Comment: Can you provide URL?

Comment: this site is on my computer, locally

Comment: What it was finally?